# Как спомошью gulp положить файлы в те же каталоге где они были до обработки

Tags: gulp

Есть задача с помощью gulp пробежаться рекурсивно внутри которым минифицировать(например) все css файлы

```js
    var gulp = require('gulp'),
    concatCSS = require('gulp-concat-css'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    notify = require('gulp-notify'),
    streamqueue = require('streamqueue'),
    jsmin = require('gulp-jsmin'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    csso = require('gulp-csso'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('css', function () {
    return streamqueue({objectMode: true},
        gulp.src([
            'www/BEM/Block/Common/Page/Page.css'
            , "www/BEM/Block/**/*.css"
            , "!www/BEM/Block/**/*_print.css"
        ])
    )
        // минификация ( можно отключать если захочется )
        .pipe(concatCSS("style.css"))
        // автопрефиксер
        .pipe(autoprefixer({browsers: ['last 3 versions']}))
        .pipe(csso())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('www/public_html/docs/css/'))
        .pipe(notify('Собрался css !'));
});
```

пробовал разные варианты с gulp.dist(...) в том числе

```
gulp.dist(function(file){ return file.base })
```

иногда даже собиралось но сыпались ошибки в консоль (различные)

Как будет сделать правильно?

Comment: нет ну pipe(gulp.dest('.')) положит в тот же каталог в котором gulpfile.js, а мне нужно чтоб либо в www/BEM/Block/Common/Page/ либо   в www/BEM/Block/** в зависимости от того в каком каталоге файл изменился

Answer (score 1):

Так пробовали?

```
.pipe(gulp.dest('.'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Привожу найденное мной решение:

```
    var gulp = require('gulp'),
    concatCSS = require('gulp-concat-css'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    notify = require('gulp-notify'),
    streamqueue = require('streamqueue'),
    jsmin = require('gulp-jsmin'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    csso = require('gulp-csso'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('css', function () {
    return streamqueue({objectMode: true},
        gulp.src([
            'www/BEM/Block/Common/Page/Page.css'
            , "www/BEM/Block/**/*.css"
            , "!www/BEM/Block/**/*_print.css"
        ])
    )
        // минификация ( можно отключать если захочется )
        .pipe(concatCSS("style.css"))
        // автопрефиксер
        .pipe(autoprefixer({browsers: ['last 3 versions']}))
        .pipe(csso())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('www/public_html/docs/css/'))
               .pipe(gulp.dest(function(file){
            return file.base;
        }));
});
```

Как оказалось, не очень и сложно было сделать.